# Find all elements based on ids using regex on jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I've got several elements with unique ids like so:

```
<div id='item-1-top'></div>
<div id='item-2-top'></div>
<div id='item-3-top'></div>
```

I was hoping that the following would work using jQuery:

```
$("#item-[.]+-top").each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

I do not have a good grasp of regular expressions and I would appreciate some input, as the above appears to be incorrect.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

*If* you were doing this with regex, the expression would simply be:

```
item-\d-top
```

Where the `\d` indicates any single digit (0..9), and the other characters have no special meaning (so are treated as literals).

However, jQuery doesn't currently have a regex filter (only things like start/end/contains/etc) - so you would have to create your own one (which is possible, but if you were considering that you should stop and consider what/why you're filtering and figure out if there's a better way first).

**Much simpler would be to create a class (as [serg555](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086554/find-all-elements-based-on-ids-using-regex-on-jquery-selector/3086636#3086636) suggests)**, since that's exactly how you're treating these items.

Or (if you can't change the markup to add the class) then use the existing filters, expanding on [g.d.d.c's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086554/find-all-elements-based-on-ids-using-regex-on-jquery-selector/3086564#3086564), I might do:

```
$('div[id^=item-][id$=-top]').hide()
```

(Since you may have multiple items ending with just 'top', either now or in future, so you need to be more specific to avoid unintentionally hiding other things.)

Comment: Thanks Peter/serg555. I tried the above e.g. and it worked a treat. It's more a case of curiosity but as serg555 suggests, using a class would be much simpler.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 16):

If the id was something like `news-top-1`, `news-top-2`, `news-top-3`, `news-top-4` etc. then the selectors would have helped you.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$.each( $("input[name^='news-top-']"), function () {
  alert( $(this).hide() );
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I would assign some class to them like `item` and then do a search by this class `$(".item")`.

Answer (score 4):

James Padolsey created a wonderful [filter](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) that allows regex to be used for selection.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^s+|s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

Now you can use

```
$('div:regex(id,item-[0-9]-top)').hide()
```

Comment: As of JQuery 3.0 this method is no longer valid. expr[':'] is deprecated.

Comment: Please update this question. Links are death and also consider the comment of Decoder

Answer (score 0):

Hit a similar problem and liked/upvoted serg's answer of creating class instead but then because I was doing multiple operations on such elements, [Keyed Collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections) were more suitable.

Answer (score -1):

`[id^='startidText']` will match id in which text start id.

`[id$='endIdText']` will match id in which text end id.

`[id*='matchIdtext']` will match id anywhere it is in the strig.

looking at the post below can also help , that wher i learnt this little
neet trick [querySelector, wildcard element match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match)