# jQuery get ID attribute using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="A1">
    <div id="child1">A1-1</div>
    <div id="child2">A1-2</div>
    <div id="child3">A1-3</div>
    <div id="child4">A1-4</div>
    <div class="A2">
        <div id="child5">A2-1</div>
        <div id="child6">A2-2</div>

        <div class="A3">
            <div id="child7">A3-1</div>
            <div id="child8">A3-2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so this is the code I have, I am looking for a way to get the number that comes after the word "child" in each ID.
I was thinking about using something like  `var values = $(‘id:contains(child)’).attr();` but it doesn't work. or maybe using regex? any suggestions? thank you

Comment: You need to read the jQuery documentation on selectors and the `.attr()` function.

Comment: This kind of question asked and answered already... Take a look at;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: similar to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086554/find-all-elements-based-on-ids-using-regex-on-jquery-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery has a concept of selectors.

You can use the following code:

## ("[id*='child']").each(function() { alert(this.attr()); });

This is called a "Contains Selector". JQuery also supports EndsWith, Child, Parent etc selectors. For more info please visit http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try :

`$('div[id^="child"]').each(function(){alert(this.attr());})`

The ^ means "start with". So it will select any id starting with 'child'

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/