# regular expression in jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="questionItem">
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MappingId must be a number." 
       data-val-required="The MappingId field is required." 
      id="answers_2__MappingId" name="answers[2].MappingId" type="hidden" value="23" />
<input id="answers_2__Item" name="answers[2].Item" type="hidden" value="B0300" />
<input id="answers_2__SetAnswer" name="answers[2].SetAnswer" type="hidden" value="^" />
</div>
```

jQuery will get me all the questionItems with this:

```
var coll = $('.questionItem');
```

I don't need all of them, I simply need the questionItems that have a child input with a name of `answers[/d+].SetAnswer` and value of `?`.

How does one construct that `has()` clause?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086554/find-all-elements-based-on-ids-using-regex-on-jquery-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't needed here. Just use `:has` and attribute selectors:

```
$(".questionItem:has(input[name$='.SetAnswer'][value='?'])");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/S8kft/

Comment: Right on the mark!  I love the jsfiddle.net site, that rock.  Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
var coll = $(".questionItem").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(":input").filter(function() {
        return /^answers\[\d+\]\.SetAnswer$/.test(this.name) && this.value == "?";
    }).length > 0;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nUNJd/