# JavaScript - multiple argument function, which is a string for multiple image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I have function like this which enables gallery by his ID:

```
    document.getElementById('galleryID').onclick = function (event) {
         event = event || window.event;
         var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
             link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
             options = {index: link, event: event},
             links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
         bg.Gallery(links, options);
     };
```

But the problem is when I have multiple gallerys in one document:

`id="gallery01"`, `id="gallery02"`, `id="gallery03"` ... up to `id="gallery11"`.

Now I multiplayed code of gallery script 11 times with different ID:

`document.getElementById('gallery01').onclick = function (event) { ...`
`document.getElementById('gallery02').onclick = function (event) { ...`
`document.getElementById('gallery03').onclick = function (event) { ...`

up to ...

`document.getElementById('gallery11').onclick = function (event) { ...`

**I wish to have one JS function not 11. How can I do this ?**

I would like to use **regular expressions** but my combinations didn't work. I think it would be very nice solution if it could be done like this - using regullar exp in place where is `'galleryID'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add event with the function call like this

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery1" onclick="getGalleryDetailFor(event)">
<div class="gallery" id="gallery2" onclick="getGalleryDetailFor(event)">
```

## Edited

```
<script>
function getGalleryDetailFor(event)
{
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
  link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
  options = {index: link, event: event},
  links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
  bg.Gallery(links, options);
}
</script>
```

## New Updated

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery1" onclick="getGalleryDetailFor('gallery1')">Gallery 1</div>
<div class="gallery" id="gallery2" onclick="getGalleryDetailFor('gallery2')">Gallery 2</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function getGalleryDetailFor(ids)
{
   document.getElementById(ids).addEventListener('click',function (event)
   {
      event = event || window.event;
      var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
      link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
      options = {index: link, event: event},
      links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
      bg.Gallery(links, options);  
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I done sth. like this and it didn't work.
`function getGalleryID(ids)
            {
               document.getElementById(ids).onclick = function (event) {...
         };
            }`

Comment: No, after this you only have to write the code inside the function which you have here in - > `{... };` and without curly braces

Comment: It still don't work. I will add whole function in my question above.

Comment: I'm affraid that solution doesn't work. I made changes which You suggested but when I click on image I can only see new document view with clean image like JS didn't start.

Comment: Have you changed onclick function with event like `getGalleryDetailFor(event)` on click of image ?

Comment: Please have a look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846268/javascript-click-event-handler-how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-the-clicked-item and its answer

Comment: Your sollution is the closest to my needs but when I apply it id doesn't work. I even used Your var names, etc. and still goes without any effect.

I see sth. like this: `links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');` which is the main argument of the function in original: `document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) { ...`

but when i change it for example using name `linksNN` it still works.

Comment: Try to get all alerts with the attributes of an elements like `alert(event.target);
  alert(event.target.src);
  alert(event.target.parentNode);
  alert(event.srcElement);` with your function then mine and try find out where it is differentiate the output.

Comment: No there is no single error in console exept one but it is connected with GoogleMaps.

Comment: The alerts are the same first is `[object HTMLImageElement]` and then 2 URLs to my image (probably thumb and origin image) and then the same like first one `[object HTMLImageElement]` but when I use my code there is showing image in slider and when Yours there is image without JS "fireworks".

Comment: So we should have to use ids of gallery anyhow, i'll let you know if I found any other solution

Comment: The trick is how to pass gallery ID to the function in script `document.getElementById('galleryID')` when user click on gallery image and call her code :/

Comment: Please look update code, I think it completes your requirement

Comment: You have to match both the functions mine and yours and check that what is the different between both that output.

Comment: Alerts are the same for both methods - Yours and mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110593/discussion-between-kirankumar-and-user3799089).

Answer (score 0):

I have two thinks:
First you can add class and use like

```
    getElementsByClassName('gallery').forEach(function(galery){
        gallery.function (event) { ...
    })
```

Or make array with all id with you want use and use forEach like

```
    ['id1','id2','id3'....].forEach(idName=>{
            document.getElementById(idName).onclick = function (event)         { ...
    })
```

edit:

mayby you should check somthing like:
[Find all elements based on ids using regex on jQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086554/find-all-elements-based-on-ids-using-regex-on-jquery-selector)

Comment: It wouldn't "fire" 11 gallerys at the same time ? galleryID should be catchet from click when user choose someone.

Comment: No it won't be fire all galery at the same time.
More details how works event in js you can find here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

in event body be carefully with use "this" property.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a general type, for example "ui-gallery" and add class to each of the elements you want to bind this event to:

```
<div id="gallery1" class="ui-gallery"></div>

<script>
// with multiple handlers for different gallery elements
var handlersPool = {
    "default" => function(event) { ... },
    "gallery1" => function(event) { ... },
    "gallery2" => function(event) { ... },
    ...
}
var uiGalleries = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-gallery");
for (i = 0; i < uiGalleries.length; i++) {
    var el = uiGalleries[i];
    el.onclick = handlersPool[el.id] || handlersPool.default;
}
</script>
```

Comment: But this solution multiply JS functions code which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If you use the same function for all of the galleries, then remove all functions except the "default" from handlersPool