# What does this line of Jquery do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this).find("a[href^='/']")
```

I'm particularly interested in knowing this part "a[href^='/']"

Comment: it's a css selector. You can make some search and learn what it do.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Refer to [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), it's explained clearly there.

Comment: This will find anchor tags whose href starts with '/' [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086554/find-all-elements-based-on-ids-using-regex-on-jquery-selector)

Comment: The '[attribute^="/value"]' selector is used to select elements whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a blatant lack of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery uses CSS selectors. `a[^='/']` will select all `<a>` whose `href` attribute starts with `/` which are children of whatever the `this` is.

See it in action:

```js
$("ul").each(function () {
  $(this).find("a[href^='/']").addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {
   background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Will not be selected</a></li>
    <li><a href="/example">Will be selected</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="/example">Yep</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Nope</a></li>
</ul>
```

- jQuery documentation on starts with attribute selector: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
- More on attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: That is better to highlight selected `a` instead write length of it.

Answer (score 1):

This particular code is **CSS Attribute Selector** to find `<a>` elements with an `href` attribute value that starts with a `/`.

More here: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

It looks for a link to the href beginning with /.