# Selecting select boxes with a text pattern and a number in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to select the list of `select` boxes with the `id` pattern as follows.

```
id_social_media-0
id_social_media-1
id_social_media-2
```

I can not use `$('select[id^=id_social_media-').each()` since there is a hidden element as `id_social_media-__empty`. I tried with `id_social_media-\d`, but it does not work.

Comment: is that hidden element also select-box ? Also has that element is hidden you can use `:visible` i.e :`$('select[id^=id_social_media-]:visible').each(function() {`

Comment: Maybe you want a regex filter function similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/28734135/12684693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simple do an oldschool for loop?

```
for(let index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++)
{
   let Element = $('select[id^=id_social_media-'+index);
   ...
```

If you don’t know the number, use a while loop and stop on no result in element:

```
var index = 0,
    elements = Array(),
    Element = $('select[id^=id_social_media-'+index);
while (Element.length) {
    elements[index++] = Element;
    Element = $('select[id^=id_social_media-'+index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [:not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude results you don't want:

```
$("select[id^=id_social_media-]:not([id=id_social_media-__empty])")
```